# Elasticsearch with JS: GET - Query not working when as Parameter

Tags: javascript, rest, elasticsearch, get

when querying my ElasticSearch with Postman, I am able to use it with GET and a query in the body:

```
{
"query": {
    "match": {
        "path":{
            "query": "uniqueIdentifier"
        }
    }
}
```

}

This results in exactly one match - just as expected.

However, because in the project I have to use JavaScript and for whatever reason JS does not allow a GET request with a body, I have to use [this workaround offered](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_request_body_in_query_string) by ES. I have tried the two following variants:

```
host/backend/something/_search?source_content_type=application/json&source={"query":{"match":{"path":{"query":"uniqueIdentifier"}}}}

host/backend/something/_search?q=uniqueIdentifier
```

However I just get returned what seems like everything in the database. No querying/matching is performed.

---

I am not allowed to use POST requests.

What am I doing wrong here? I am following the guide offered by ES, however there are no examples.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Do you have any document with `.html` extension?

Comment: I am searching for the exact same string with both methods. I removed the .html in the example.